# Define a php variable in the Wordpress admin page view

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have created a wordpress template that has the following snippet of code:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>    
<?php
$location ="";
?>
```

In the wordpress admin, I would like to create a page, and in the page editor define the variable $location. The only trouble is I can't put PHP code in the edtior and the php-exec-plugin isn't working. The reason I need to do this, is that depending what the location parameter is, this affects other content in the page. (but this must be controlled via the wordpress admin.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)? In the post editor, add a field e.g. `scott_location` and a value. In your template, use the value like:

```
$loc = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'scott_location', true );
if( $loc == 'atlantis' ){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks diggy, I like the look of this solution, I'll give it a go tonight and let you know how i get on! thank you

Comment: diggy, that solution is gold dust. thank you worked flawlessly!